# Entity Framework with ASP.NET MVC is saving value to wrong column

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have the following classes, a challenge has many submissions and it also has a winner.
The problem is that in my database Entity framework has created two columns on the Submissions table [ChallengeId] & [Challenge_ChallengeId] when I save an object it is added to the ChallengeId Column but relationship is being held on the Challenge_ChallengeId column.

Is there an issue with my models that is causing this or is some way I can set to hold the relationship and save to the same column?

Thanks!

```
public class Submission
 {
    [Key]
    public Int32 SubmissionId { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Int32 ChallengeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ChallengeId")]
    public virtual Challenge Challenge { get; set; }
    public String YouTubeVideoCode { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<SubmissionVote> Votes { get; set; }
}

public class Challenge
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 ChallengeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public String ChallengeName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }

    public Int32? OverallWinnerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OverallWinnerId")]
    public virtual Submission OverallWinner { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could benefit from just using the conventions and also using the shorthand keywords as data types. I think the error is because you have annotated the proxy with a ForeignKey attribute. Try this

```
public class Submission
{
    public int SubmissionId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public int ChallengeId { get; set; }
    public string YouTubeVideoCode { get; set; }

    public virtual Challenge Challenge { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SubmissionVote> Votes { get; set; }
}

public class Challenge
{
    public int ChallengeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ChallengeName { get; set; }
    public int? OverallWinnerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Submission OverallWinner { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that Entity Framework uses a convention based approach, and the easiest way to fix this is to use the `Id` name instead of `ChallengeId` and `SubmissionId`

```
public class Submission
 {
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Created { get; set; }

    public Int32 ChallengeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ChallengeId")]
    public virtual Challenge Challenge { get; set; }
    public String YouTubeVideoCode { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<SubmissionVote> Votes { get; set; }
}

public class Challenge
{
    [Key]
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String ChallengeName { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Submission> Submissions { get; set; }

    public Int32? OverallWinnerId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OverallWinnerId")]
    public virtual Submission OverallWinner { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `<ClassName>Id` as primary key is also an EF convention. The `Key` attribute is not necessary.